# chrome not showing background image, but it shows on changing any value from google developer tool

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

this question is may sound funny. But I am sticking here. In one of my websites background image of a specific div not showing up. So I checked it with chrome developer tool by pressing f12. There I changed the position of the div. And I made change in the correspondent css also. But even if I reload the website it doesn't shown up. So I cleared chrome caches. Then I reloaded websites, still it is not showing. The embarrassing thing is that, on changing any value from developer tool, makes the background image visible, but not if I change it in css. For example,

> My div is "A". There I have a background image and it is not showing.
>   I pressed f12 and changed the color of another div "B" which has no
>   relatiom between div"A", the background image showing on browser

, It works perfectly in mozilla. I am wondering how it is happening and why? Any one can help me? thanks in advance.

this pic is before changing value in f12
[image: pic1]

And this one is after changing any values in developer tool
[image: [pic2]

This is my page.

[enter link description here](http://redeemergroup.com/index1.php)

Comment: Did you get it resolved ?

Comment: Nop.. Since that was an urgent work, I removed it and built another one. It worked perfectly.. :)